# custom REST endpoints and application passwords

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I have created a number of RESTful endpoints via a plugin. To date I have only accessed them from the host site. However I would like to access these endpoints from a sub-domaine(2ed Wordpress installation). An application password appears to be a good way to set up authentication for accessing these endpoints in my application. However I can not find any documentation as to how to modify my 'permission_callback' to recognize application passwords.

Comment: There's been a major misunderstanding of what `permission_callback` does here. The `permission_callback` callback is not meant to authenticate users, it's meant as a check that an already authenticated user has access to that endpoint, e.g. via roles and capabilities. WordPress itself implements the login authentication, be that via cookie + nonce, or application passwords, not the endpoint

Comment: No I understand what permission_callback is for, The confusion I have not been able to resolve is how WordPress site 1( the one with the RESTfull extensions,) knows anything about users on Workpress site 2 a client of the RESTfull endpoints provided by Wordpress site 1. The user is authenticated on site 2, but site 1 knows nothing about that user.

Comment: it isn't, you can't use a user on site 1 to login to site 2. To login to a WP site you need to login to a user on that specific site. You can do that via basic auth with a username and password of a user on that site, or with an application password set up by a user on that site, but it's specific to that site. If you are on site 2, and want to make an authenticated request to site 1, you need the credentials of a user on site 1. It's the same as if you tried to talk to the google or FB APIs, you don't use your apps user details to login to those, you use FB details, or Google details

Comment: what that has to do with `permission_callback` I do not know, `permission_callback` is equivalent to `current_user_can`, not `is_user_logged_in`, and framing it that way in your mind will only create more confusion. To clarify, site 1 has no idea about the users on Site 2, and vice versa, and site 1 has no idea if the user is logged into site 2 or not, much the same way my site has no idea if you are logged into your site. Also, site 1 makes no attempt to check if the user of site 2 is logged into site 2, that would make no sense. Site 1 is only interested in the users of & requests to site 1

Comment: so if you want to make a request to site 1 that require authentication, you need to authenticate with site 1, and user an application password that was created on site 1, with a user that exists on site 1. This is true regardless of where the request comes from, be that site 2, mobile application 3, or site 1 itself.

Comment: if you have a user/browser -> client WP site REST API -> host site REST API situation, there are 2 sets of credentials: "browser <-> client WP REST API" and "client wp <-> host WP REST API". Your client WP API would need to act as a proxy, taking in requests it authenticated with the user, then making new separate requests to the host WP that had their own authentication. This sound very unwieldy though, especially if the user is meant to login with a user/pass that comes from the host WP as now you have to do a tonne of complicated syncing. It's much easier to use a multisite and share users

Comment: Also, what does your plugin do? If you had shared what you were trying to build then explained your problem it would have saved a lot of time and you would have gotten much better answers from myself and Ameen

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't think this will work in this case. Site 2 does need to know who the user is that is logged in. I thought I could off load some tasks from site 1 to 2. and access what I needed using a single user and application password.  I think i will be better off sharing the database between the two sites.  It is a shared calendar, where volunteers can sign up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use application passwords to authenticate requests to your RESTful endpoints, you can modify your permission_callback function to check for the presence and validity of an application password instead of a user's credentials.

To do this, you can use the wp_check_application_passwords function, which was introduced in WordPress 5.6. This function takes an application password and a user ID (or a username) and returns a WP_Error object if the password is invalid or expired, or an array with information about the password if it's valid. Here's an example of how you could modify your permission_callback function to use application passwords:

```
function my_rest_permission_callback( $request ) {
    $app_password = $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Application-Password' );

    if ( empty( $app_password ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_forbidden', __( 'Authentication required.' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // or get the user ID from the request data

    $result = wp_check_application_passwords( $user_id, $app_password );

    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_forbidden', $result->get_error_message(), array( 'status' => 403 ) );
    }

    // Here you can do additional checks or data processing based on the password information
    // ...

    return true; // Access granted
}
```

In this example, the permission_callback function retrieves the X-WP-Application-Password header from the request, which should contain the application password provided by the client. If the header is empty, the function returns a 401 Unauthorized error.

The function then calls wp_check_application_passwords with the current user ID and the application password, and checks if the result is an error. If so, the function returns a 403 Forbidden error with the message from the WP_Error object. Otherwise, the function assumes that the password is valid and returns true to allow access to the endpoint.

You can customize this code to fit your specific needs, such as checking additional information in the password result or handling errors differently. Note that you need to create and manage application passwords in the WordPress administration area, under the user profile of the user who will be making the requests.

Comment: This is not how application passwords are meant to work, and bad practice

Answer (score 1):

It would use `is_user_logged_in()`. It's WordPress' job to authenticate the user not yours. `permission_callback` is there to test if that user has access, e.g. can an editor access this endpoint:

> **The permissions callback is run *after* remote authentication**, which sets the current user. **This means you can use current_user_can to check if the user that has been authenticated has the appropriate capability for the action, or any other check based on current user ID.** Where possible, you should always use current_user_can; instead of checking if the user is logged in (authentication), check whether they can perform the action (authorization).

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback

If you are testing WP user logins, application passwords, etc in your `permission_callback` then this is incorrect, and not how the REST API works.

Authenticated requests to the REST API are either:

- basic auth with application passwords
- cookie sessions + REST API nonce

WordPress will log the user in and create sessions on its own, it does all of that for you. Your code only needs to know `is_user_logged_in()`, and you don't need to do anything special for 3rd party remote clients.

Comment: And how does the endpoint know they are logged in when they are coming from a remote website?

Comment: it doesn't, it's not the job of the endpoint to figure that out, WordPress handles user sessions and authenticated endpoints don't implement the authentication by hand themselves. They just check that you're logged in. _How_ they are logged in is none of your business, all you need concern yourself is the return value of `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: note that if you are writing code in your REST API endpoints checking user passwords, creating user sessions, etc, that is incorrect and not how REST API endpoints work. WordPress is meant to do all of that for you, and that's not what that callback is there for. This is why the other answer is incorrect, and bad practice