# Application password header not checked in REST API

Tags: php, plugin-development, rest-api, third-party-applications

I have this code in my custom plugin. I've created an application password and I want to check it every time a custom endpoint is called.

```php
        register_rest_route( 
            $this->namespace, 
            '/activation-check', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array($this, 'send_activation_emails'),
                'permissions_callback' => function( WP_REST_Request $request ){
                    $application_password = $request->get_header('Authorization');
                    if(empty($application_password)){
                        return new WP_Error(
                            'Forbidden',
                            __('Forbidden'),
                            array(
                                'status' => 403
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        //
                        $user = wp_check_application_passwords($application_password);
                        //
                        if(is_wp_error($user)){
                            return new WP_Error(
                                'Forbidden',
                                __('Invalid application password'),
                                array(
                                    'status' => 403
                                )
                            );
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            ) 
        );
```

I've noticed that the endpoint will use the callback also if no authorization header is sent with the ajax requests. Is there something I can do prevent that the endpoint can give sensistive data if the application password isn't provided?

Comment: I believe the application password just authorises the request as coming from the user who the password belongs to. So your permissions callback should just be the normal permissions check for the user's role/capability/authorship. You shouldn't need to authenticate the password yourself.

Comment: I need to check the application password because I'm calling this custom endpoint from a nodejs script. If the application password is present, I will need to do some code stuff otherwise return 403. I don't want to replace normal user login with this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you show an example of checking?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback

Comment: I know that dev docs section, I was meaning if there is a way to check the application password into the permissions callback

Comment: There should be [a determine_current_user filter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.3.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L492) that processes the application password for you. I think they still run for the REST API. So you shouldn't need to check it again yourself.

Comment: Similar question here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/414041 And I think it's [wp_validate_application_password](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_application_password/), not check, and it doesn't take the header as an argument.

Comment: @ICTDEV I’ve explained that you’re not supposed to check the password. If the user permissions check passes then it means the application password is valid. The permissions_callback check should be agnostic towards the authentication method.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ok, so the application password is checked also if  the user isn't logged but have a valid one right?

Comment: @Rup I need to test the `current_user_can()` function, since I'm calling the endpoint from an external script, I will only provide the application password, the associated user that is a superadmin will never login. This is why I supposed to use a check inside the permissions callback

Comment: @ICTDEV The user does not have to be logged in, no, if I'm understanding your question correctly. Using the application password authenticates the request as coming from that user, so any permission checks will be based on that user's role and capabilities, but it does not require or create a session for that user.

Comment: Yes, essentially the nodejs script that will call the endpoint will access to it only after verification and return the supposed callback processed data